# Protect Table from insertions, but remain available for read

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a large table of lookup data only. I want to lock table so no insertions are allowed (password protected?). Users will look up data on two fields to find a result in the third field. In general users will have read write permissions on all other tables in the DB.

Comment: You can't make a table password protected. You can prevent inserts with an instead of trigger. You can also DENY insert for certain (or maybe all) users. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx

Comment: Better yet, don't `GRANT` people permissions you don't want them to have. By default, nobody can do anything to a database. If your concern is that users might make changes to a particular table, that's only a concern if you've already gone past the point of granting them permissions to do so. So stop and ask yourself why you gave them those permissions to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative that would block update and insert on a specific table but still allowing delete:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT chk_read_only CHECK( 1 = 0 )
```

Be aware: this avoids INSERTs and UPDATEs, but allows DELETEs.

If you really need a table to be truly read only you could also either:

a) put it in its own database or
 b) put it on a file group and mark that read only, here’s how:

```
USE [master]

GO

ALTER DATABASE [name] ADD FILEGROUP [READONLYTABLES]

GO

ALTER DATABASE [name] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'mydb_readonly_tables', FILENAME = N'G:\SQL2005DATA\mydb_readonly_tables.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [READONLYTABLES]

GO

USE Name

GO

DROP TABLE mytable

CREATE TABLE mytable (

    somedata    char(8000) not null

) ON READONLYTABLES

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this page which explains a few solutions:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2711/different-ways-to-make-a-table-read-only-in-a-sql-server-database/

The below is probably what you are after (add tables to a FILEGROUP and then set that group to READONLY):

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] ADD FILEGROUP [READ_ONLY_TBLS]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] 
ADD FILE ( NAME = N'mydb_readonly_tables', 
FILENAME = N'C:\JSPACE\myDBReadOnly.ndf' , SIZE = 2048KB , 
FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [READ_ONLY_TBLS]
GO

DROP table tblEvents

create table tblEvents
(
id int,
logEvent varchar(1000)
)
ON [READ_ONLY_TBLS]

ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] MODIFY FILEGROUP [READ_ONLY_TBLS] READONLY
```